# Not able to call a rest API while closing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to call a rest API using AJAX call in javascript in beforeunload function(closing browser event). It was working well before Chrome version 80. Now in version 83, i am not able to call the service and get a message 'Disallow sync XHR in page dismissal'. I tried below options :
1.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
 var dataURL = "https://dummyurl";
              fetch(dataURL, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  keepalive: true
                }); 
});
```

2. `AllowSyncXHRInPageDismissal` policy flag set to Enabled.

Could you please help us to provide some alternate solution?